# WSO2 EI custom exception or error message in REST API

Tags: wso2, wso2-enterprise-integrator

Can we create custom exception in a REST API? We can use Fault mediator for proxy services. Do we have same kind of option for API's as well.

I need this because I'm using fault sequence to log errors in third party system. For this purpose once error is thrown I'm sending custom message to a REST API. Since this log message is success I'm not getting an error to original client who calling my rest api and end up with 200 OK.

So can we create a custom fault once after fault sequence is invoked?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can create a custom fault sequence and add it inside the API. Further, you can modify it as you required.

**Sample API:**

```
<api xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse" name="testAPI" context="/test12" version="1.0" version-type="context">
   <resource methods="GET" faultSequence="CustomFault">
      <inSequence>
         <log level="custom">
            <property name="message" value="Inside the API"/>
         </log>
      </inSequence>
   </resource>
</api>
```

Sample Fault Sequence :

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<sequence name="CustomFault" xmlns="http://ws.apache.org/ns/synapse">
    <log level="full">
        <property name="MESSAGE" value="Executing default 'fault' sequence"/>
        <property expression="get-property('ERROR_CODE')"
            name="ERROR_CODE" xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
        <property expression="get-property('ERROR_MESSAGE')"
            name="ERROR_MESSAGE"
            xmlns:ns="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd" xmlns:ns3="http://org.apache.synapse/xsd"/>
    </log>
  </sequence>
```

Comment: I can't get working custom fault sequence in WSO2 APIM 4.0.0.

In log I get only messages `Executing default 'fault' sequence`